# Entity framework does not show entities properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added .edmx file but when i want to used this as a below

```
DB121212123524Entities entities = new DB121212123524Entities();
entities.SiparisGroup.....
```

it shows entities name (it shows SiparisGroup entity), but it is not show entities properties name (SiparisGroup  entity has SiparisGroupId but it does not show after dot).

This is siparisGroupEntity

[image]

This is controller (there is no entities property)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
DB121212123524Entities entities = new DB121212123524Entities();

DB121212123524Entities is probably a DbContext and entities.SiparisGroup is a DbSet.  Of course it won't show the entity properties.
```

you need to query first the entities from a specific table, in this example I'm using `SingleOrdDefault()`

```
var entity = entities.SiparisGroup.SingleOrDefault();
```

then the object entity object should have the properties you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you must use this code for access entity property
if i Undrestand Correctly

```
entities.SiparisGroup.Where(a=>a.MemberID == 1).ToList();
```

OR

```
var Table = entities.SiparisGroup.singleOrDefualt(a=>a.PrimaryKey == 123)
```

Comment: Be very careful about the second example, calling `.ToList()` on the table will result in an object being created for _every_ row!